# Calculate Network usage using nettop in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, network

I want to calculate the network usage like some apps do(which displays `up` and `down` which changes it's values by the usage of user)

**Using `nettop`:**

```
nettop -t wifi -t wired -P -l 1
```

But then I saw [this repo](https://github.com/gjiazhe/Up-Down/blob/master/Up%26Down/NetWorkMonitor.swift) in Github.

The command used there is

```
nettop -x -k state -k interface -k rx_dupe -k rx_ooo -k re-tx -k rtt_avg -k rcvsize -k tx_win -k tc_class -k tc_mgt -k cc_algo -k P -k C -k R -k W -l 1 -t wifi -t wired
```

Now I'm getting different values in `bytes_in` and `bytes_out` for both the commands.

**For the first command:**

```
Google Chrome.284     153 KiB         150 KiB
```

**For the second command:** Taken from github

```
Google Chrome.284     156895          152847
```

**Q).** I ran `second command` first and `first command` second. So obviously the `first command` data should be equal or greater than `second command`. But it's wrong when I converted(`150*1024 = 153600`) Why is that? Which command should I use?